# Solve $\dfrac{x}{x-2}>2$ by first rewriting it in the form $\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Edit: So then is this the correct final solution? $x<4,(\infty,4), x\ne2$

I am asked to do this:

Solve $\dfrac{x}{x-2}>2$ by first rewriting it in the form $\dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)}>0$

$$\dfrac{x}{x-2}>2$$
$$\dfrac{x}{x-2}-\dfrac{2(x-2)}{1(x-2)}>0$$
$$\dfrac{x-2x+4}{x-2}>0$$
$$\dfrac{-1(-x+4)}{x-2}>0$$
$$\dfrac{x-4}{x-2}<0(x-2)$$
$$x-4<0$$
$$x<4$$

Comment: Advice in the future: As a sanity check, try $x=0$. It is greater than $-4$, but $x/(x-2)=0 \le 2$. This means something went wrong. See the answers below for where your mistake is.

Comment: See this [solution to the problem](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F%28x-2%29%3E2&lk=4&num=1)

Comment: would you accept a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct. You can perform the following operations:

$$\dfrac{x}{x-2}>2$$
$$\dfrac{x}{x-2}-\dfrac{2(x-2)}{1(x-2)}>0$$

However, your error occurs on the second line:

$$x - 2(x - 2) = x -2x + 4$$

Comment: corrected this.

Comment: @nitrous2 that was the only problem with your question. Everything else was fine. Please upvote.

Comment: So the interval for this inequality would be $(4,\infty)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your method not is correct because: if

$$\frac{4-x}{x-2}>0\equiv-1\cdot\frac{(4-x)}{x-2}<(-1)\cdot0\equiv\frac{x-4}{x-2}<0$$

then $(x-4)>0$ and $(x-2)<0$, or $(x-4)<0$ and $(x-2)>0$

solutions $2<x<4$

Answer (score 0):

Check Second Line$$\cdots-2(x-2)=\cdots-2x+4$$